a cool optimization problem involving cubes surfaces and volumes
Consider a codimension one surface of revolution $S$ and an embedding $e:S \hookrightarrow X^n$ for $X^n=[0,1]^n$ with points $p,q$ elements of $\partial X^n$ where $\partial X^n=X^n-(0,1)^n$ for $\mathrm {sup}~ \mathrm{dist}_n(p,q)=\sqrt{n}$. Assume $S$ must remain a surface of revolution, have constant positive Gaussian curvature, and have a pair of antipodal corner points $p,q$ as cone points.

Is $\rho_n=\max \lbrace \mathrm{vol_n(S)} \rbrace=\mathrm{a~universal ~constant}$ for all $n\ge 3$?

This answer estimates the volume for $n=3$ to be $\approx 1/2$. There are several competing geometric constraints which makes it hard to get a read on the long term behavior of the volumes. I think these competing constraints will cancel each other out making the volumes constant. For some heuristics: The hypercube near $p,q$ puts constraints on how large the volume of $S$ can be in each dimension. Also, the volume of the unit hypercube gets more and more concentrated near the vertices and edges of the hypercube as $n\to \infty$.
